# "Thanx to" or "Thanx"?

Tags: usage, verbs, imperative-sentences

I want to have two different meanings as:

1. I am grateful to Ali.
2. I order Ali that he should be thankful to Zohaib.

Which of the following is used in each case:

- "Thanx Ali" or "Thanx to Ali".

Comment: Neither. Use *thanks*, with a *-ks*, not an *-x*. The latter makes you look immature, or lazy, or both. In re: "thanks" vs "thanks to", the former is used when you're communicating directly with Ali, one-on-one; the latter is used when you're communicating to a broader audience that you (or you and some other people, possibly the very audience you're addressing) are grateful to Ali. In re: Zohaib, if you want to instruct Ali to express his gratitude, you'd say "Ali! Say *thank you* to Zohaib!" Or "Ali! Tell Zohiab you're thankful". You probably would *not* say "Ali! Give thanks to Zohaib".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the verb "to thank", which means *to express gratitude*.

**I thanked him for helping me.**

We have the noun "thanks" which means *gratitude*.

We can say "You have my thanks" to someone who has helped us or has been generous in some manner.

The adjectival version of "thanks" is "thankful", like "grateful"; it means to be "full of thanks" or "full of gratitude". In other words, it means to be full of the *feeling* that we call gratitude.

Commanding someone to be full of gratitude is futile because we cannot command someone to *feel*.  However, it is possible to command someone to *express* gratitude, since the expression of gratitude is an *action*, not a feeling.

So you could say:

**I commanded Ali to thank Zohaib.**

Comment: What about "thanks" in the context as stated by **Dan Bron** above?

Comment: Dan Bron mentions "thanks" in several places in his comment, so I'm not sure which instance you are referring to. Please clarify your question. Thanks  P.S. If you are referring to "Give thanks", that means "to express thanks" (to give someone our thanks) but it is somewhat archaic and is used mainly in prayers and expressions of piety.  If Zohaib is a great and powerful ruler, then it could work. But to say things in this manner would truly exalt Zohaib.

Answer (score 0):

Some usage examples:

1. If you are grateful to Ali, then the next time you meet him, you might want to say, "Thanks, Ali!"
2. If you tell Ali to express gratitude to Zohaib, then Ali should thank Zobaib the next time they meet by saying "Thanks, Zohaib!"

In no case should you spell it as "Thanx" — that is only for when you are writing an SMS and need to save one character (in which case you'd probably write "Thx").